# tqdm iterating beyond range of iterable

Tags: python, tqdm

I'm using tqdm to iterate over my val_loader. However, it is returning the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Develop_Model_2.py", line 261, in <module>
    None)
  File "Develop_Model_2.py", line 217, in training_loop
    for X, y in pbar:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1178, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 517, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 557, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py", line 330, in __getitem__
    return self.dataset[self.indices[idx]]
  File "Develop_Model_2.py", line 72, in __getitem__
    yimg = Image.open(self.maskList[index]).convert('L')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anyone have an idea about why this might be happening as I can't figure out from my code. It seems the problem is the final iterable from tqdm is out of bounds.

```
pbar = tqdm(val_loader, total = len(val_loader))
for X, y in pbar:
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    X = X.to(device).float()
    y = y.to(device).float()
    model.eval()
    ypred = model(X)

    val_loss_arr.append(loss_fn(ypred, y).item())
    pixelacctest.append(pixelAcc(y, ypred))
    meanioutest.append(meanIOU(y, ypred))

    pbar.set_postfix({'Epoch':epoch+1+prevEpoch,
                      'Validation Loss': np.mean(val_loss_arr),
                      'Mean IOU': np.mean(meanioutest),
                      'Pixel Acc': np.mean(pixelacctest)
                     })
```

Comment: Please always post the *full* traceback message, as text (so that it becomes searchable).  We can't even tell which line failed given only that tiny portion of the error.

Comment: edited to show error, sorry

Comment: Have you tried it without `tqdm`?